# Trying to append letter to text inside input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text input that is disabled using the disabled attribute, but I add input to it on the click of a certain classes.

On the click of class I (.I), I add a letter I to the existing text, if any, inside the input.

On the click of class O (.O), I add a letter O to the existing text, if any, inside the input.

However nothing seems to be happening when I click the classes.

Here is my code:

```
    $('.I').click(function(){
        $('#code').text($('#code').text()+"I");
    });
    $('.O').click(function(){
        $('#code').text($('#code').text()+"O");
    });
```

Here is a JSFiddel replicating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/q3xBY/

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Comment: is code wrapped in `document.ready`? Do classes exist when code is run? Create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: @user1479606 Updated the question with a fiddle.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, it is. I updated my question with a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get and set the value of an input element, you should use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

```
$('.I').click(function(){
    $('#code').val($('#code').val()+"I");
});
$('.O').click(function(){
    $('#code').val($('#code').val()+"O");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoded each click like that, you can give same class for all your button:

```
<button class="I button">I</button>
<button class="O button">O</button>
```

Then you can apply jQuery to achieve like what you describe:

```
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('input:text').val(function(index, val) {
        return val + text;
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q3xBY/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

As John S said - you're going to want to use `.val()` and not `.text()`. In case you have multiple instances of this on one page and you don't want to repeat yourself I've provided a solution.

`#foo` is the text input you'd like to change when you click on the text input modifiers. The `ul[data-change]` can be the container for the modifiers and has a `data-change` attribute to specify which `input` element on the page the modifiers will target. Each of the `a` modifier elements have a `data-value` attribute that specifies what will be added to the targeted `input` on `mouseclick`.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" value="" disabled="disabled" />
<ul data-change="#foo">
    <li><button id="i" data-value="i">i</button></li>
    <li><button id="a" data-value="a">a</button></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('[data-change] button').on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).closest('[data-change]').data('change');
   $(target).val( $(target).val() + $(this).data('value') );
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpC6D/1/